# Excel Power Query and Adjacent Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I'm running into an odd situation with Power Query and formulas. The query refreshes the linked table exactly as needed. I've added a few columns with formulas that manipulate the data. This happens 'on-sheet' and not in the Power Query. However, if I hard-code a value into the formula (say the formula produces 19.52 but I know that the applicable data point is 19.0) and refresh the data, the hard-coded data is erased and replaced by the existing formula. These hard-coded data points are added ad-hoc.

Is there a way to get the Refresh to stop/ignore auto-updating non-Power Query columns? It seems like the Refresh All button is refreshing the entire table (which is probably the intended use).

Comment: If you want to preserve hardcoded data, then it has to live somewhere outside of the refreshable table.

Comment: In any case it's generally bad practice to have table columns with a mixture of formulas and static values.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions:

1. **Ideal** : Keep the hardcoded data is a serpate sheet, load to Power Query and formulate within Power Query using merge feature, if this is possible.
2. **Not an efficient use of resource** : Create another sheet, link the Power Query output (Entire output or the columns you need), and add your Manual Columns for your calculations.